Can we do a projection measurement on a subspace of a given quantum state?
Given a state $\sum_{0<i<M_1} \left|i\right>$, can we do a projection measurement on a subspace to get $\sum_{0<i<M_2} \left|i\right>$, where $M_1 > M_2$. I am new to quantum algorithms, if you have any suggestion for lecture notes about that, I appreciated.

You cannot do that with 100% probability using just a projective measurement. The probability that you can succeed depends on $M_1$ and $M_2$. Define two normalized states
\begin{align}
|M_1\rangle &:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{M_1}} \sum_{i=1}^{M_1} |i\rangle \tag{1} \\
|M_2\rangle &:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{M_2}} \sum_{j=1}^{M_2} |j\rangle , \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
and then consider the projective measurement defined by the two operators, $\{I - |M_2\rangle \langle M_2|, |M_2\rangle \langle M_2|\}$. Starting with $|M_1\rangle$, the post measurement state is $|M_2\rangle$ with probability
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(|M_2\rangle) &= |\langle M_1 | M_2 \rangle|^2 \tag{3} \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{M_1 M_2}} \sum_{i=1}^{M_1}  \sum_{j=1}^{M_2}  \langle i |j\rangle \right|^2 \tag{4}
\\&=  \frac{M_2}{M_1}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
So, the smaller the support of $|M_2\rangle$ is (relative to $M_1$), the harder it is to prepare $|M_2\rangle$ by projective measurement alone. In general, the success probability for any such projective measurement is directly related to the inner product $\langle M_1 | M_2\rangle$, which becomes small when $M_2 << M_1$.
